# how to create a GNU screen session with multi windows in it?

Tags: gnu-screen

I alway work in a screen session with some windows, one for shell, one for mysql, one for music player, one for irc, and so on...

The problem is, when you create a screen session, it only creates one window by default. So I have to do `Ctrl-a c` then issue commands, again and again.

So I wrote a bash function to do this.

```
d(){
        local i=workspace
        screen -qls $i
        if [ "$?" -ne 11 ];then
                screen -dmS $i
                screen -S $i -X screen mysql -uroot -p
                screen -S $i -X screen irssi
                screen -S $i -X screen nvlc $music -Z
                screen -r $i -p0
        else
                screen -r $i
        fi
}
```

My question is, is there a way to start a new screen session with **some** windows? By this question, I mean **new session**, NOT for existing sessions using '**`-X`**'. And, screen built-in feature, I mean, no shell scripting involved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't consider .screenrc file at first, because commands in it will be invoked every time you call screen, but sometimes I need to create a new screen session with different things.

One thing I forgot is that, I can choose configuration file.
So I think answer is:

```
d(){ 
    screen -d -R -S workspace -c ~/.workspace
}
```

and content of ~/.workspace should be:

```
screen
screen mysql -uroot -p
screen irssi
screen nvlc
select 0
```